# Sync to Async http request and response architecture

Tags: java, spring, architecture, microservices, spring-webflux

We are developing a **REST service** (2) that act as a adapter between a blackbox **Client** (1) and blackbox **Processor microservices** (4).

(2) and (4) communicate with each other using **Kafka** (3)

All components are stateless (except Kafka, right?)

First, **Client** initial a command to **REST service** using http POST (sync), then **REST service** take this command and forward it to **Processor ms** (after doing some conversion) via **Kafka** (async).
After this step, **REST service** will sleep (this http scope) and wait the result from **Processor ms**

Then **Processor ms** handle this command and send the result back to **REST service** via **Kafka** (async). **REST service** wake up and and return the ResponseEntity to **Client** within same http scope.

Now we decide to migrate (2) to microservice to take advantage of this architecture. And the problem occurred: instance 1 of (2) send command to (4), and (4) send the result to instance 2. But the http session is established between (1) and instance 1, and instance 2 cannot return to (1). This returning must be done by and only by instance 1.

My first idea is, for example, let instance 1 be aware of the result from (4) no matter it was sent to which instance. But currently we have no solution to archive this idea.

This is the diagram [image: diagram]

We need a "non work-around" solution for this architecture. Please help. Thank you

Note: we are unable to make change to blackbox components

Comment: Could you create a per-host/instance topic in Kafka and then only instance subscribes/publishes to the given topic?

Comment: if we do this, we must make change to blackbox (4), right? Since (4) have to decide which topic it should use to send response

Comment: Potentially, you'd have to provide more info about Blackbox (4) and how it leverages Kafka. Another option is sending your request directly to the Blackbox (4) instance, but you'll have some trade offs with that.

Comment: (2) publish a message to (4) on a topic `request`. (4) send result to (2) on a topic `response`

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat straight forward - In short: You need to make sure you look for the right events only.

That means the events posted on the result queue have to be identifiable being intended for that specific client and not another client. You can do that by including a guid, for example.

Subsequently your REST service will keep looking for result events but discard them except if they indicate they are for his specific client.

Here is a diagram showing this principle. Note that the REST service is only looking for "Client 1" events:

[image: Overview REST Service & Processing Service Communicate via Event Queue System]

Comment: Can you suggest a suitable event queue implementation? Is redis suitable (1M - 10M events per some minutes)

Comment: I personally like Apache Pulsar and Kafka those are scalable and should work for your scenario. Usually you want to carefully design how many topics you use for which purposes in order to scale more easily and possibly over multiple clusters if your throughput is high. Also look into how different guarantees impact performance in your scenario and configure those wisely.

Comment: We cannot use kafka since we cannot force kafka to push message to correct instance. If we can do this, I have not to ask this question

Comment: Hence my answer. Let me know if there is anything that is not clear about how to solve it like that.

Comment: I think your diagram is the same to mine if (3) is still kafka. We need a replacemnt at (3) to be able to route messages to correct instance in a set of instances

Comment: Definitely not the same. Try to find the differences and also read my description.

Comment: Kafka is push model, we cannot force it to push this message to this instance. The only way to do this with kafka is creating one topic per http request, then the response will be route to this topic only, but it lead to millions of topics per some minutes

Comment: Kafka is not a push model and neither is my explanation. Please read the docs: https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html 
 https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html

Comment: It means we can "pull" message from kafka, or we can decide which message will go to which consumer, right?

Comment: Yes, consumers (clients) can subscribe to topics and decide which events they wish to consume/acknowledge.

Comment: I think "The only way to do this with kafka is creating one topic per http request, then the response will be route to this topic only, but it lead to millions of topics per some minutes"

Comment: I think the approach suggested by @OswinNoetzelmann is a std solution (pattern), i.e. by inserting some identifier and then filtering responses based on that. It even has a common name, but i cannot remember :) However, since you say (4) is a blackbox, i think it may be impossible to implement his or any other solution, because you can probably not introduce additional topics and or tamper with messages between (2) and (4)?

Comment: By the way, how does this relate to microservices? Wasn't (2) running multiple instances before the transition, e.g. for providing HA etc?

Comment: (2) was monolithic, so one topic for it was enough. Now we upgrade it to microservice pattern, it lead to the unexpected behavior described on my question. We have a work around solution is creating one topic per http request, then the response will be route to this topic only, but it lead to millions of topics per some minutes since this is large system

Comment: This answer is very good, but I would like to know more detail how to apply it, since our Kafka is not working here

Comment: If you can create topic per http request, this means you can configure how (4) interacts with kafka, correct? Then just create 2 topics, one for "requests", one for "responses". Have (4) listen to "requests" and push to "responses" topics. Now you have to configure (2) to listen to "responses" and have instances consume only their own responses and discard others. How will instances recognize their own "responses"? They can either look at some identifier in the message, or inject a new identifier while they send the "request" to kafka. Beware of multithreading in (2) instances as well though..

Comment: PS I have found the link i was looking for: https://www.developertoarchitect.com/lessons/lesson1.html

Comment: I think the problem of Kafka not working is that each instance of the Rest service can only consume a portion of messages from the Kafka topic as the topic is partitioned and we cannot control which partitions to subscribe unless each instance use own consumer group but then it results in so many consumer groups. One approach is to create one topic for each service instance by e.g. UUID and each instance only watches its own one. Still it can create many topics while instances get restart or upgraded but the amount is manageable and some house keeping ops is needed to clean up the old topics.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I would:

- either process like Oswin proposed, and create one group of consumer per RestService instance. This ensures that **each** RestService instance can consume **every** response events but process only the ones that match the expected uuid
- or (seems more optimized) create one response topic per RestService instance and send the name of the response topic in the command event. The consumer  should send the response event in the correct response topic. That way, each RestService instance would read **only** its response topic, and would **only** receive and process response events of which he is the recipient